# Script extracts and prints UTF-8 words well, but prints JSON as garbage

Tags: json, perl, utf-8

I have tried my script on Mac OS Mavericks (perl 5.16.2) and Yosemite and also with Windows 7 (strawberry-perl-5.20.1.1-64bit-portable).

It is supposed to read UTF-8 data (russian text) and put it into a data structure - and finally print the data structure as JSON string (the output will be used to feed Core Data in an iOS word game).

The first part works (extracting words and printing them - to verify) works well, but the final part not: the resulting JSON string contains garbage:

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody please know, how to fix my simple test script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use JSON;

binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');

my $root = { words => [] };

while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        utf8::decode($_);
        my @a = split /\s*[:,]\s*/;

        my $words = [];
        for my $word (@a[1 .. $#a]) {
                print "WORD: $word\n";
                #push @$words, utf8::encode($word);
                push @$words, $word;
        }

        push @{$root->{words}}, $words;
}

print to_json($root, {utf8 => 1, pretty => 1});

__DATA__
Голова: небо, язык, мозг, глотка, надгортанник, пищевод, горло, гортань
Сумки: портмоне, кошелек, портфель, рюкзак, лямка, застежка
```

Comment: PS - `utf8::decode($_);` shouldn't be there because `use utf8;` already decodes the source code (incl DATA). It's currently failing (silently), but it could mangle your data.

Comment: Actually in my real script I don't read `<DATA>`, but read another files by using `while (<>)` and that is why I have added `utf8::decode($_)` so that regex works on the read lines.

Comment: Use `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`. It decodes STDIN, encodes STDOUT and STDERR, and sets the default encoding for files opened in its lexical scope. This includes those opened using `<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're double encoding. You're encoding using `from_json` (`utf8 => 1`), then you're encoding again when outputting to `STDOUT` (`binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');`).

The solution isn't clear, because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you're really going to output non-JSON and JSON to STDOUT, don't ask `from_json` to encode.

Answer (score 3):

The output looks "wrong", but that's OK: it's encoded. To see it correctly, just set

```
binmode STDOUT, ':raw';
```

before printing the JSON.

You can simplify the script by using `encode_json`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use JSON;

binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $root;

while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @words = split /\s*[:,]\s*/;
        push @{ $root->{words} }, [];

        for my $word (@words[1 .. $#words]) {
                print "WORD: $word\n";
                push @{ $root->{words}[-1] }, $word;
        }
}

my $json = encode_json($root);
binmode STDOUT, ':raw';
print $json;
```

Comment: His code also works, if he just adds `binmode STDOUT, ':raw';` after `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");`

Comment: If I add `binmode(STDOUT, ":raw");` then it fact this works, when I redirect script output to a file. There is a warning `Wide character in print`, but the resulting file is ok.